# How to parse JSON to viewpager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-json

I am a beginner at the android studio. I have parsed some JSON data from the server. I want to implement these data in a viewpager. I got A sample viewpager code. But when I apply these JSON data to list it shows cannot resolve constructor. My Viewpager code is below.
My JSON Fetching code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
// Constants
private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

// UI Components
private VerticalViewPager mVvpMainPager;

// Other objects
private ViewPagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    initView();
}

private void initView() {
    mVvpMainPager = findViewById(R.id.activity_main_vvp_main_pager);

    setupViewPager();
}

private void setupViewPager() {
    mPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    for (BeanNews news : generateSampleNewsData()) {
        mPagerAdapter.addFragment(PagerFragment.newInstance(news), "News " + news.getNewsId());
    }
    mVvpMainPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
    mVvpMainPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(generateSampleNewsData().size());
}

private ArrayList<BeanNews> generateSampleNewsData() {
    String url ="http://maranamassapp.cf/json_getdata.php";
    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("server_response");
                        for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
                            JSONObject ser =jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            String creatorname =  ser.getString("head");
                            String imageUrl = ser.getString("image");
                            String cat = ser.getString("content");
                            String postdate = ser.getString("weburl");
                            String dateall = ser.getString("date");
                            BeanNews news = new BeanNews(creatorname,imageUrl,cat,postdate,dateall);
                            ArrayList<BeanNews> newsList = new ArrayList<>();
                            newsList.add(news);

                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    });



    return newsList;
}
```

Comment: Please post your BeanNews class

Comment: Hello Nasim welcome to Stack Overflow. What do you mean by **how to apply these JSON data to the viewpager** Did you mean showing data in ViewPager's `Fragment`s? Could you please paste your xml too? Not sure what you're trying to achieve now.Thanks

Comment: @ʍѳђઽ૯ท  I have edited and updated the full code. Thanks For Your Response.

Comment: @umang-burman  I Have Added The Full Code. THanks For Your Response

Comment: Post Your BeanNews Class

Comment: Check [this link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager) about `ViewPager`. Now, you'll need a `RecyclerView` or a `ListView` inside `ViewPager` xml layout file to show the data. That's why i said please paste your xml codes. So, you'll need `Fragment` inside `ViewPager`, A `RecyclerView` inside `Fragment` then showing data or adding to `RecyclerView` adapter. Check the documentation or [this](http://androidcss.com/android/fetch-json-data-android/).

Answer (score 0):

**Check [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager) about `ViewPager`:**

> Layout manager that allows the user to flip left and right through
>   pages of data. You supply an implementation of a `PagerAdapter` to
>   generate the pages that the view shows.
>
> `ViewPager` **is most often used in conjunction with `Fragment`**, **which is a
>   convenient way to supply and manage the lifecycle of each page.**

Now, you'll need a `RecyclerView` or a `ListView` inside `ViewPager` xml layout file to show the data. So, you'll need `Fragment` inside `ViewPager`, a `RecyclerView` || `ListView` inside `Fragment` then showing data or adding to `RecyclerView` adapter.

Can't actually pass list of items(*from json in your case*) to `ViewPager` to show on the view in Android.

Comment: iam not using recyclerview because i want to show one JSON object per viewpager.

Comment: You actually have to use `Fragment`(s) inside `ViewPager`. Look for it [in here](https://medium.com/@kyroschow/how-to-use-viewpager-for-navigating-between-fragments-with-tablayout-a28b4cf92c42). Then, use `RecyclerView` or `ListView` to set `Adapter` for your items in each `Fragment`. Check the link to see how it works. The way you think how `ViewPager` is working is not correct I'm afraid.

Comment: can you do me a project for money.

Comment: No need for money. My god please :] I'll help you it's alright. Just try to join this conversation: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179702/conversation  or my email in my profile. I've added you to have access to write. Hope you can make it.